# Vuex mutation updates state, computed property never reflects update in markup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

This issue hasn't been touched in a while but i'm running into something confusing on my end when using a computed property for a textarea value.

I have a textarea where you give input text and on input it updates the input text in vuex:

```
<textarea
ref="inputText"
:value="getInputText"
@input="setInputText"
class="textarea"
placeholder="Your message goes in here"
></textarea>
```

On the click of a button to translate the text I call a `handleInput` method.

```
handleInput() {
    this.$store.dispatch("translateEnglishToRussian");
},
```

In my store I have my `translateEnglishToRussian` action:

```
translateEnglishToRussian({ commit }) {
    const TRANSLATE_API = "https://XXXXXXXX.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/YYYY/";
    const data = JSON.stringify({ english: this.state.inputText });

    this.$axios
    .$post(TRANSLATE_API, data)
    .then(data => {
        commit("setOutputText", data.translatedText);
        commit("setMP3Track", data.mp3Path);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I see it call `setOutputText` mutation with the payload of translated text, in my vue dev tools I see the correct state with the translated text. However, my second text area that's being used purely to display the translated text *never updates!*

Output textarea:

```
<textarea
disabled
ref="outputText"
:value="getOutputText"
class="textarea"
></textarea>
```

Its value is bound to a computed property called `getOutputText`:

```
getOutputText() {
    return this.$store.state.outputText;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here! Any advice is appreciated. I thought this should be fine since i'm using `commit` in my vuex action in a synchronous way (inside the then() block).

Edit: I have the same result if I also try using `v-model`. The initial output text from vuex state is rendered there on page load. When I translate, I see the update in Vue Dev Tools correctly, but the text in the text area never re-renders.

Edit #2: Here is my `setOutputText` mutation:

```
  setOutputText(state, payload) {
    console.log(`state - set output - ${payload}`);
    state.outputText = payload;
  },
```

Comment: can you include your 'setOutputText' mutation?

Comment: what are you seeing updated in the Vue Dev Tools? can you confirm if this.$store.state.outputText retrieves the correct value in your computed method?

Comment: @NickDechiara thanks for replying, I have updated the question with the snippet you asked for!

Comment: @ryeMoss I am seeing my state in Vue Dev Tools appropriately updating with the translated text after i do an axios post to my lambda endpoint. I commit the value to `setOutputText` in the then() block.

Comment: Take a look at [Multiline text](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Multiline-text). Try to change `:value="getOutputText"` to `v-model="getOutputText"`. Because it's computed property, you should add `get` and `set` [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the vue docs for [Multiline text](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Multiline-text), you should replace `:value="getOutputText"` with `v-model="getOutputText"`.

Because it's computed property, to use it in `v-model` you need to add `get` and `set` to your computed property

```
<textarea
  disabled
  ref="outputText"
  v-model="getOutputText"
  class="textarea"
></textarea>
```

**EDIT**: Per *@Stephen Tetreault* comment, `v-model` didn't work for him, but `:value` did solve the problem at the end.

```
computed: {
  getOutputText: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.$store.state.outputText;
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      // there is no need to set anything here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i'll try this when I get back home!

Comment: this didn't work :(. My mind is seriously blown right now, this is a trivial task i've done before albeit not on a textarea but it shouldnt matter. No matter what i'm doing, the state updates correctly in vue dev tools the textarea just never re-renders with the proper text!

Comment: Just noticed that there is a typo `:v-model` instead of `v-model`. Sorry about that

Comment: No worries, I caught the missing `:`. It still doesn't work, its very weird. Like I mentioned, the state gets updated but even this doesn't cause the textarea to re-render with the updated output text from the state :(

Comment: Ah it finally works, I really have no idea what changed I feel like I'm going crazy. I removed the v-model but kept the computed property with get/set like you suggested. I kept `:value="getOutputText"` on the tag just for the hell of it since the v-model one wasnt working. Now it FINALLY re-renders the text. What a weird occurrence I havent run into such a little pain before and use `:value` like this often. thanks for your help in troubleshooting!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you solved this. I was testing this on `vue@2.5.17` (`npm list vue` in your project to see the version). Who knows, in theory, `v-model` [is just is a syntactic sugar](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) for `:value` + `:input`